# Using Flash and Swing w/ Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionscript-3, flash

I want to create a program that is able to connect to an online Flash game. Essentially what I need is somebody to point me in the right direction. I've done some research and I cannot find anything about Java integrated with flash when it's an online game.

I want to grab the game client (which was programmed in flash) and send a login web requests to the server, grab cookies, log the account in and then display the game on my program. Is this possible?

**Here are some basic questions:**

- Will I need the source of the flash game?
- Are there any imports that include flash?

My Java is very limited as of current, but I am studying at school and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should set up some webservice(soap or rest) between the two application to get the necessary data back and forth...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You have to understand that what you just said doesn't actually mean anything to me at all because I am half a programmer.

What exactly is a webservice and what does it do?
Why would I need it?
Can you think of any other methods?